# как выкинуть ошибку в другом классе?

Tags: c++

подскажите пожалуйста,у меня есть два класса.В одном я валидирую пришедшую дату на правильность.А второй класс это исключение с моим текстом.Вопрос состоит в том как мне правильно кинуть эту ошибку в другом приватном методе другого класса?

```
class InvalidDate {
public:
    std::string text;
    InvalidDate(const std::string& text) : text(text) {}
```

};

вот код. Подскажите правильность написания синтаксиса и вызова этого класса.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под ошибкой? Может быть исключение?

Comment: Про `throw` читали?

Comment: да.читал.Просто в данном случае как то так все складываться что не могу понять как ее кинуть @HolyBlackCat

Comment: да.я про исключения.Просто в этой задаче я могу сам написать текст ошибки,поэтому так написал.C терминологией еще не очень дружу @Kotomi

Comment: `throw InvalidDate("...");` Все. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw

Comment: спасибо!помогли! @Kotomi